# all my images and colours gone leaving just blue outlines Xcode 9

Tags: xcode9

Hi all I am working with Xcode 9 beta Version 9.0 beta (9M136h). it was all working ok but then suddenly became sluggish. I reset Xcode and my computer and now I am getting this when I open my project. all my images and colours and nabbers and nav controllers are missing but they are replaced with blue lines. If I run the program it runs fine, and if it i open it in Xcode 8 all the images show.  Has anyone else had this?

[image]